# Trying pass new list item ID via variable: create

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow-variable

In SharePoint online, I created a declarative (designer) workflow on **List A**. The workflow is triggered on item created.

When a new item is created on **List A**, it creates new list item in **List B**.

Once the item gets created in **List B**, I'm trying to update the List A item.

But currently its's not working. Please suggest some workaround.

Latest workflow[image] screenshot:

Comment: first add  logs , and find the error.

Comment: Workflow History is not showing any errors

Comment: Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
using List A workflow you are creating Item in List B, You want to get List B created item id in variable

Comment: Correct. i would like to update List A with the List B ID variable

Comment: please check Updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some workaround for this

- Create hidden custom column name **ListAID** in List B which save list A current item ID.
- In declarative workflow create variable , like if List B item **ListAID**
  Column value is equal to **List A** item ID, then get List B **ID** column value in
  variable

please see below screen shot 
[image]

Here you need to use lookup

Comment: If you are adding Unique title, then no need to create ListAID column in List B, Just Replace ListAID with Title in Screen Shot.
means compare List A title with List B Title then get ID of List B Item. keep me posted, if you need more details

Comment: I am using a unique name so i will use that. after the steps in your screenshot, in order to update list A with the List B ID do i need to add a Update List Item to the workflow?

Comment: No need to use action Update Item, instated of that  you can user action     Set field value

Comment: Hi, thanks for your assistence. I believe i have set my workflow as per your instructions however the result is still not occuring.

Comment: Can you Please add Screen shots of your workflow, so I can help you.

Comment: saved screenshot at top

Comment: I think you selected wrong "Field from source". Please select "ID" instead of "Cnum ".
please check that 
Field "Name" and value  "Current Item : Cal_Name"  having same text

Comment: I have tried both cnum & ID (cnum is actually a calculated field adding a static number to ID) but neither is successfull for me. Name & Calc_Name also do have the same text. Both are calculated fields but the end result is the same in both. Would this impact the working of this solution or is there something else i need to consider?

Comment: have you tried the method,that I had describe in answer. If not try at least once for testing purpose. using that you will figure out what is wrong with your workflow.